# what would be the equivalent to document.GetElementById().files for IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

I am currently building a file upload page and it does not work in IE because the getElementByID().files is not supported in IE (or so I read) does anyone know the equivalent that would work in all browsers?

Comment: What is `.files` supposed to return? What element is it supposed to work on?

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what information you're trying to get - because I have a horrible feeling you're going to get hit by standard security restrictions

Comment: -1 because the question is not clear and precise.

Comment: It is clearly talking about [the File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)

Comment: Yes Quentin, I am talking about the file API, sorry I was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

IE has no built in API. You need to use a plugin such as Flash.

There is a list of [polyfills for HTML 5 features](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) that includes some for the File API.